# Gremlin console addV seem not to add vertices

Tags: gremlin

In Gremlin Console, in order to add a vertex, I do the following:

```
// One time initialization
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()

// Add the vertex
g.addV('somelabel')
```

And in the console i get:

```
==>v[0]
```

But if I try to traverse the vertex:

```
g.V(0)
```

I get nothing in the console, as if the index was wrong.

A proof of that (the fact i get nothing) is:

```
g.V(0).count()
==>0
```

If instead i define the id myself:

```
g.addV('somelabel').property(id, 1)
```

Everything works fine:

```
g.V(1)
==>v[1]
```

But I would not like to define the ids myself...

Where am I doing (or thinking) wrong?

Software version is JanusGraph 0.2.2, Apache TinkerPop 3.2.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using JanusGraph here but TinkerGraph, an in-memory graph store that is often used for testing or simple examples.
TinkerGraph uses long ids by default which means that it cannot find your vertex when you use an `int` id. It should work when you use parameter of type `long`:

```
gremlin> g.addV('somelabel')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V(0)
gremlin> g.V(0L)
==>v[0]
```

The [configuration section for TinkerGraph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.4/reference/#_configuration_3) explains how this configuration can be changed to use different types for its integers.